# Is there a way to clone DOM elements without separate object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm interested in making ghost preview elements of very complex DOM objects. While I know that I can just clone the element, I was wondering if there was a hacky way to make a system of tags be rendered twice? I wouldn't mind using webGL or what other steep methods that I can; I'm just interested in seeing what options there are. Any ideas? No jQuery, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can experiment with [-moz-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-element)

Comment: Neat idea, sorry for late accept. Any ideas for workaround for the fact it's only `-moz-`?